# Why is the owner of the clearcase activity 'nobody'

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Why is the owner of the clearcase activity I created is 'NOBODY' but the created by is identified correctly.

Is this the reason why I am not able to view the change set as a different user on a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are representing object (here UCM activities) created by a user with an incorrect [`CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135509) (ie a group he/she isn't part of, or a group which isn't part of the primary or secondary groups of the vob/pvob of the UCM project).

I usually fix that (as a ClearCase admin) with a:

```
cd M:\auser_dynamic_ucm_view\avob\a_root_component
cleartool find . -user NOBODY -exec "cleartool protect -chown a_login_name -chgrp agroup \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

That would fix incorrect *files* though, not UCM activities.

For an activity, I would do a:

```
cleartool protect -chown a_login_name activity:anActivity@\apvob
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the above command with just -print and it did not return anything. The vob/pvob were created on the Linux server. The primary group of the vob/pvob is unix group ccusers. I am creating the activity on the windows side and my CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP environment variable is set to windows DOMAINNAME\ccusers. Do you think that is the problem? How do I make sure the group map.

Comment: @clearcase the mappings seems fine. You should check it with `credmap` (an utility for 'credential mapping'): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21132158. The '`NOBODY`' usually pops up when you create an activity while your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` wasn't properly set yet. Do you still have '`NOBODY`' when you create a new activity?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to credmap VonC. I did a credmap and my user on windows is mapped to NOBODY on unix side...onto some investigation now..