# Ownership issue while checking out file from dynamic view which is synced from unix

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I synced dynamic view from unix to windows and checked out the file.
I want to check in the file from the unix site but the ownership is set on "`Nobody`" on the checked out file which means checkin is not possible from unix site.

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nobody  citco1       529 Oct 16 01:29 file.h
```

But I checkout out another file from unix and it is Ok.

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pditi  citco1       529 Oct 16 01:29 file1.h
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a:

```
cleartool protect -chgrp rightGroup aFile
cleartool protect -chgrp rightGroup aFile@@
```

(the second protect the "element", the first only protect the version)

Next time, check your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable on Windows.

You should set it to the primary group of the vob of the file modified:

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\yourVob
```

Then delete and recreate your view, and try again a checkout/checkin.

On Unix, the file should keep its group.

See also, for more: "[Why is the owner of the clearcase activity 'nobody'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17335157/6309)". (a similar issue for UCM activity)

Comment: CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP is Ok. Possible of samba mapping issue?

Comment: @user2370590 to make sure `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` is ok, you need to do a `credmap <clearcase server hostname>` and check if the group is correctly matched.

Comment: VonC, credmap <hostname> generated my user name and cc primary grp are Ok. what else to check next?

Comment: @user2370590 you need to check that the "`Identity on local system`" "`Primary Group`" returned by `credmap` match the one on Unix ("`Identity on host "clearcase_server_hostname"`"), returned by the same `credmap`.

Comment: One thing I want to share is unix Id and windows Id are different, is this an expected behaviour if the Id's are different even though they are mapped?

Comment: @user2370590 yes, what counts is: 1/ identical group, 2/ the SID: NT on Unix should be the one of the Windows account.