# While creting a view I got this error; cleartool: Error: Failed to record hostname in storage directory

Tags: clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am creating a view and I got this error cleartool: Error: Failed to record hostname  in storage directory .
Check that root or the ClearCase administrators group has permission to write to this directory.

I tried all the possible troubleshoot using online help and others, but no luck. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the technote "[Registering a VOB or creating a new View or VOB reports error: Failed to record hostname](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21234135)"

```
View Tool

Error creating view - '<view-tag>'

Fail to record hostname " HOST " in storage directory "<path to view storage>. 
Check that root or the ClearCase administrators group has permission to write to 
this directory.
Unable to create view "<global path to view storage>".
```

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21234135&aid=1]

### Cause

> The cause of the error ultimately stems from the inability of ClearCase to successfully record the hostname in the `.hostname` file located in the storage directory of the VOB or view.

In addition of the various solutions, check if that error persists  on different clients, for different users.
If not, it is likely linked to your profile.
Check for instance your [`CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` and your credmap (credential mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331166/why-is-the-owner-of-the-clearcase-activity-nobody#comment25170039_17335157).

---

In my case, it was always a case of applying the right `fix_prot` to the view/vob storage.
For view storage, it was that exact sequence:

```
alias sfp sudo /usr/atria/etc/utils/fix_prot

sfp -force -rec -chown <owner> -chgrp <ClearCaseUsers> -chmod 775 /path/to/viewStorage/yourView.vws
sfp -force -root -chown <owner> -chgrp <ClearCaseUsers> /path/to/viewStorage/yourView.vws
```

Replace `<owner>` and `<ClearCaseUsers>` by the right owner and group.

Comment: @knm the line *just above* `sfp` *defines* what `sfp` is: an alias for `fix_prot`.

Comment: As a general practice, *do not* use fix_prot -root on a view as it will wipe the view's additional groups. The result is that you would be able to start the view, but you may not be able to open files associated with groups other than the primary group. On *unix* you can fix this by creating "group" files in the .../{whatever}.vws/.identitiy files and making them setgid for the group in question. But for windows you could render the view at best partially useful.

Comment: @BrianCowan Good to know. I have done it countless of times, but I suppose I was using the right groups.

Answer (score 0):

On *creating* a view, other common problems for remotely stored views are:

1) The "clearcase" group on the client and server do not point to the same group. You would need to get clearbug2's of both hosts and compare the albd credentials and the host data in the registry data in the "clearcase_info" directory of the .zip file.

2) You are attempting to create a Unix-hosted view from a Windows client.