# Input output error in ClearCase diff. Improper argument

Tags: windows, unix, clearcase

I have a user who is getting an error when they are trying to access another's view.  When they try to do a diff they **input/output error** on xcompare in unix and in windows they receive ***failed to display version tree browser for element Encountered  an improper argument*** on the windows side.  I have no issues doing this in either of the user's view.  They both are a member of the correct group and the view was created with that group.  What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on the exact version of your ClearCase.
For instance, this [technote mentions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM90756) (Windows)

> When accessing a file or directory in the IBM Rational ClearCase GUIs, for example, ClearCase Explorer or the Version Tree Browser, that has permissions of 770, you will receive an error: "Encountered an improper argument" rather than "Access Denied" or "Permission Denied" if you are not a member of the group that owns the element.

While the users might be part of the correct group (ie their CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP) is the same as the Vob group), double-check their permissions and their view permission.
This [technote details](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21635518):

> If a principal has not been granted access to a VOB, an attempt to access the VOB from IBM® Rational® ClearCase Explorer returns the error, "Encountered an improper argument."
>
> This error might imply insufficient permissions.
>   To determine the effective ACL on the object, use the command:
>
> ```
> cleartool describe -eacl vob:\vobtag \vobtag
> ```

Regarding the view:

```
cd /path/to/my/view 
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

A `fix_prot` on the view might be necessary: see an example of such a `fix_prot` in "[While creating a view I got this error; cleartool: Error: Failed to record hostname in storage directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19535355/6309)"