# Change 'Created By' in ClearCase UCM

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is there a way to change the created by of an element?

The problem is someone made a change to a file as Domain.Users (I am not sure why it did not error out). Since it was first change to that file the stream and the first revision on that file is created as Domain.Users. Now the problem is other users are not able to checkout that file. It give permission denied errors.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should, as an admin, be able to do a:

```
cleartool protect --chgrp agroup afile@@
```

Note the final two `@@`, in order to protect the *element*, and not the version.

See:

- [man `cleartool protect`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm)
- "[Summary of protection commands and utilities used with ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21211784)":
  The `protect` command sets the owner, group, or permissions for elements, shared derived objects, or VOB objects which are maintained in the VOB database.
  The main use of protect is to control access by standard programs to an element or object's data. For example, you can make some elements readable by anyone and make others readable by only their group members.
- "[Why is the owner of the clearcase activity 'nobody'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17335157/6309)" for protecting the owner, and not just his/her group.
- "[Change ownership of all objects in a VOB using the find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146517)": that combines a `cleartool find` with a `cleartool protect`, in order to protect all the files that need it.

Also, make sure your user has a `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` user environment variable set to the right group (ie the main group of the Vob), and that user is actually registered in said Vob group, in order for the next checkout/checkin version to be correctly protected.